# making a class variable global in throught the application

Tags: objective-c, global-variables

In my application there are lot of view controller in some view controller some variables are there which i want to use in other classes .my variable is not present in application delegate file so i can i make it global to use every where in my application?

Comment: is ur viewController accessible from appDelegate..?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, how about using singleton pattern? So when you want to use the variables of that class, just get instance and then use the variables.

```
@interface MySingletonViewController : UIViewController
{
  //here your variables
  int globalVariables;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int globalVariables;
+ (MySingletonViewController *)sharedSingleton;
@end

@implementation MySingletonViewController
@synthesize globalVariables;
static MySingletonViewController *sharedSingleton = nil;
+ (MySingletonViewController *)sharedSingleton
{
  @synchronized(self)
  {
    if (sharedSingleton == nil)
      sharedSingleton = [[MySingleton alloc] init];

    return sharedSingleton;
  }
}

@end
```

UIViewController is class actually, so we can do this way : ) Hope this helpful.

Comment: I think that controlling UIViewController lifetime via + (MySingletonViewController *)sharedSingleton not good idea. Better would use standalone class of options, that are helpful application-wide.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can, but using global variables through entire app is definitely broken architecture design.

As Objective-C based on C, you can define variable (in you case - pointer to class) in any *.m file outside implementation part as:

```
MyVeryOwnClass *g_MyVeryOwnClassPointer = nil;
```

And access it as:

```
extern MyVeryOwnClass *g_MyVeryOwnClassPointer;
/* do some operations with your pointer here*/
```

Or move extern declaration to header file.

PS: You can use singletons. They are not the best solution, but better then using raw variable.